# Foreign key compatibility with entityframework 3

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I am working on an ASP.Net Core MVC application.

I have changed netcoreapp2.0 to netcoreapp3.1.

Everything works except the database. I have a runtime error: A query runned on sql-server does not keep field names in fk.

Here is my model:

```
Table("customers")]
public class Customers
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public long customer_id {get;set;}

   ...

   [ForeignKey("group_id")]
   public long? group_id {get;set;}
   public virtual CustomerGroup group { get; set; }

   ...
```

When i try to get Customers in my app, sql-server runs this kind of query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN groups ON customers.group_id = groups.group_id
```

This was working great on netcoreapp2.0.

But here is what is runned now, on netcoreapp3.0 :

```
SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN groups ON customers.customersgroup_id = groups.group_id
```

As you can see, EF adds a prefix on the FK field.

What should i do in order to keep compatibility between my previous version ?

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure you haven't changed the model? For instance, adding `public virtual CustomerGroup group { get; set; }` navigation property? Anyway, the `[ForeignKey]` attribute is incorrect - either move it on `group` property, or keep it where it is now, but change it to [`ForeignKey("group")]`.

Comment: In fact, everything i put in ForeinKey("xxxx") is ignored. I have the same result even if i put: ForeinKey("helloworld")

Comment: Well, it is ignored if it is invalid (like your "helloworld" example). And if it is valid, it definitely is taken into account, except if there is fluent configuration overriding it (do you?). The place of that attribute is important, because when applied on FK property it expects the name of the navigation property, and vice versa. Since I was not able to reproduce the exact issue and if proper `ForeignKey` attribute really does not solve it, I guess there is something custom (fluent API code) not shown here, so [mre] is needed.